# Why does this throw an error on XAMPP:CANT ADD FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does this throw an error "XAMPP:CANT ADD FOREIGN KEY".

The create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE FIR_T (
FIR_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
Incident_date DATE NOT NULL,
Incident_place VARCHAR(30),
Time_lodged TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Incident_time TIMESTAMP,
Date_lodged DATE NOT NULL,
Petitioner_id VARCHAR(15),
Victim_Name VARCHAR(50), 
Victim_Address VARCHAR(100),
Case_id INT(10),
Petitioner_Name VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT FIR_PK PRIMARY KEY(FIR_id),
CONSTRAINT FIR_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(victim_name,victim_address) 
REFERENCES Victim_T(name,address),
CONSTRAINT FIR_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(Petitioner_id,Petitioner_Name)
REFERENCES Petitioner_T(NIC,Name),
CONSTRAINT FIR_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(Case_ID)
REFERENCES Case_T(Case_ID));
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, there's no need to yell, provide an exact error message, and please tag your question with an appropriate RDBMS.

Comment: re-tagged with `mysql` based on the `int(5)` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Do the types of the child and parent columns for your foreign key match exactly ? If yes, is there any existing data in the table that would violate the foreign key constraints you are trying to add ?